# Confirmation box not working jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to replicate this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/vvjj8/ in my local machine but its working at all. When I click yes or no button there is no response even in debugger console there is no error message, I don't know what I am missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#dialog-confirm").html("Confirm Dialog Box");
      // Define the Dialog and its properties.
      $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
          "Yes": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(true);
          },
          "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(false);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    function callback(value) {
      if (value) {
        alert("Confirmed");
      } else {
        alert("Rejected");
      }
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <div id="dialog-confirm"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `z-index` to the `.ui-dialog`:

```
.ui-dialog {z-index: 999;}
```

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/gixemolubu**

Comment: that link is blocked here can u use jsfiddle

Comment: hey praveen can you add a comment box in that confirmation

Comment: @saurabh You can add a `<textarea>` inside buddy. Yes. Add like this: `<div id="dialog-confirm"><textarea></textarea></div>`

Comment: @saurabh Lemme check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100447/discussion-between-saurabh-and-praveen-kumar).